# Filtering within an window function (over ... partition by)?

Tags: sql, window-functions

I am  trying to use a sum() over (partition by) but filter within that summing. My use case is summing trailing twelve months up to a single month's entry for each product, so:

```
ITEM    MONTH    SALES
Item A  1/1/2011     2
Item A  2/1/2011     5
Item A  3/1/2011     3
Item A  4/1/2011     7
Item A  5/1/2011    12
Item A  6/1/2011     8
Item A  7/1/2011     9
Item A  8/1/2011    15
Item A  9/1/2011     6
Item A  10/1/2011    7
Item A  11/1/2011   12
Item A  12/1/2011    1
Item A  1/1/2012     3
Item A  2/1/2012     4
Item A  3/1/2012     5
Item A  4/1/2012     6
Item A  5/1/2012     4
Item A  6/1/2012     8
Item A  7/1/2012     9
Item A  8/1/2012    12
Item A  9/1/2012    14
Item A  10/1/2012    8
Item A  11/1/2012   12
Item A  12/1/2012   16
```

Would then return:

```
ITEM      MONTH_BEGIN SALES TTM SALES
Item A    1/1/2012        3        87
Item A    2/1/2012        4        88
Item A    3/1/2012        5        87
Item A    4/1/2012        6        89
```

Where the TTM SALES for 1/1/12 is the sum of 1/1/11-12/1/11

Comment: What SQL have you tried? What is your question?

Comment: What database software and version are you using? It helps to tag your question with it, e.g. `sql-server-2008`.

Answer (score 10):

The bellow query shows how I would do it with [Oracle Analytic Functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions004.htm):

```
SELECT
   "ITEM",
   TO_CHAR("MONTH", 'MM/DD/YYYY') AS "MONTH_BEGIN",
   "SALES",
   SUM("SALES") OVER (
    PARTITION BY 
       "ITEM" 
    ORDER BY 
       "MONTH" 
    RANGE BETWEEN 
       INTERVAL '12' MONTH PRECEDING
       AND 
       INTERVAL '1' MONTH PRECEDING
   ) AS "TTM_SALES"  
FROM
   "SALES"  
ORDER BY
   "MONTH";
```

[Working SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e1ac4/45)

---

This will compute the sum function over a window that starts 12 months before the month of the current row and ends 1 month before it.

I assumed that you do not need to filter anything in the where clause. If you do, be careful with it. Quoting the [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions004.htm):

> Analytic functions are the last set of operations performed in a query
>   except for the final `ORDER BY` clause. All joins and all `WHERE`, `GROUP
>   BY`, and `HAVING` clauses are completed before the analytic functions are
>   processed.

So lets say that you want to display results only for **the first quarter of 2012**; if you try to do so by filtering in the where clause,  it will affect the cumulative results of `TTM_SALES` as well (outputing `null`, `3`, `7` and `12`).

The bottom line here is: If you need to filter out rows within the window of the analytic function, move the analytic function to a subquery and filter in the outer query as per @peterm answer:

```
SELECT 
   "X"."ITEM",
   TO_CHAR("X"."MONTH", 'MM/DD/YYYY') AS "MONTH_BEGIN",
   "X"."SALES",
   "X"."TTM_SALES"
FROM
(
   SELECT
      "ITEM",
      "MONTH",
      "SALES",
      SUM("SALES") OVER (
       PARTITION BY 
          "ITEM" 
       ORDER BY 
          "MONTH" 
       RANGE BETWEEN 
          INTERVAL '12' MONTH PRECEDING
          AND 
          INTERVAL '1' MONTH PRECEDING
      ) AS "TTM_SALES"  
   FROM
      "SALES"  
   ORDER BY
      "MONTH"
) "X"
WHERE 
  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM "X"."MONTH") BETWEEN 1 AND 4
  AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM "X"."MONTH") = 2012;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're open to anything other than an analytic `SUM()` then here is a possible solution with a simple correlated subquery

```
SELECT s.item, s.month month_begin, s.sales,
       (SELECT SUM(sales) FROM sales 
         WHERE month BETWEEN DATEADD(month, -12, s.month) 
                         AND DATEADD(month,  -1, s.month)) ttm_sales
  FROM sales s 
 WHERE s.month BETWEEN '20120101' AND '20121201'
```

Sample output:

```
|   ITEM |                      MONTH_BEGIN | SALES | TTM_SALES |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| Item A |   January, 01 2012 00:00:00+0000 |     3 |        87 |
| Item A |  February, 01 2012 00:00:00+0000 |     4 |        88 |
| Item A |     March, 01 2012 00:00:00+0000 |     5 |        87 |
| Item A |     April, 01 2012 00:00:00+0000 |     6 |        89 |
...
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dce2d/10)** demo

Comment: so uncivilized... postgres has ```min(...) filter(where ...) over(partition by ... order by...)```